# Copy Javascript "Class" Prototype to an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I have a created a *class* `User`. It has some properties like: name, id, password, etc.

I've set up a constructor like:

```
function User(name1, email, password) {
  this.name = name1;
  this.id = __GUID();
  this.type = __TYPE;
  this.addNewEmail(email);
  this.password = (new Password).createFromRawPassword(password).crypt;
}
```

And some prototype functions like:

```
User.prototype.save = function(cb, callback) {
  return cb.bucket.upsert(this.id, this, function(err, res) {
    if (callback == null) {
      return callback(err, res);
    }
  });
};

User.prototype.addNewEmail = function(email) {
  this.emails = this.emails || [];
  return this.emails.push(email);
};
```

This works pretty nice for me, and let's me store my object as serialized JSON (in a couchbase database with NodeJS) without including in the object the functions.

The problem comes when I get the object from DB. It comes with all the properties, as stored, but I need to add back the functions. I have tried to use some `extend` functions for mixins that I found, but they add the functions as ownProperties, and therefore, next time I save the updated record to DB, I get the functions saved.

**How can I turn the received object into a object of type User again?** To get the required methods of the class appearing also on the instance.

Comment: Found a temporary solution: ``instance.__proto__ = User.prototype``, but I find it very awkward. Is this ok for Node.js? Any other good solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiple ways to do it:

this is roughly the same as your way:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, User.prototype)
```

you can instantiate a new object and copy properties:

```
var obj = Object.assign(Object.create(User.prototype), instance);
```

you can use any `extend` implementation instead of `Object.assign` (it's not available natively yet)

or you can change your `User` implementation to store all fields inside of a single property, which is object

Comment: Second option looks better, I just create a new instance and add all the properties of the JSON file.